# Custom parsing function for any number of arguments in Python argparse

Tags: python, argparse

I have a script that gets named parameters via command-line. One of arguments may be supplied multiple times. For example I want to run a script:

```
./script.py --add-net=user1:10.0.0.0/24 --add-net=user2:10.0.1.0/24 --add-net=user3:10.0.2.0/24
```

Now I want to have an argparse action that will parse every parameter and store results in a dict like:

```
{ 'user1': '10.0.0.0/24',
  'user2': '10.0.1.0/24',
  'user3': '10.0.2.0/24' }
```

Also there should be a default value that will be supplied if there's no value provided. Like

```
./script.py
```

Should have dict like:

```
{'user': '192.168.0.0/24'}
```

I believe that I have to build a custom action for argparse. What I came up with is:

```
class ParseIPNets(argparse.Action):
    """docstring for ParseIPNets"""
    def __init__(self, option_strings, dest, nargs=None, **kwargs):
        super(ParseIPNets, self).__init__(option_strings, dest, **kwargs)

    def __call__(self, parser, namespace, values, option_string=None):
        for value in values:
            location, subnet = values.split(':')
            namespace.user_nets[location] = subnet

parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description='foo')
parser.add_argument('--add-net',
                    nargs='*',
                    action=ParseIPNets,
                    dest='user_nets',
                    help='Nets subnets for users. Can be used multiple times',
                    default={"user1": "198.51.100.0/24"})

args = parser.parse_args()
```

That works fine when I need to use default value:

```
test.py
Namespace(user_nets={'user1': '198.51.100.0/24'})
```

However when I add parameters - they got appended to default value. My expectation is that they should be added to an empty dict:

```
test.py --add-net=a:10.0.0.0/24 --add-net=b:10.1.0.0/24
Namespace(user_nets={'a': '10.0.0.0/24', 'b': '10.1.0.0/24', 'user1': '198.51.100.0/24'})
```

What's the right way to reach what I need?

Comment: Why did you think they would be added to an empty dictionary? You're providing a mutable argument; perhaps it would be better to make that a subsequent step if the user hasn't provided anything?

Comment: That was exactly the mistake I've made. The solution provided by @serge-ballesta worked like a charm.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As it is clear that `argparse` internally puts the default as initial value of the resulting object, you should not directly set the default in the `add_argument` call but do some extra processing:

```
parser.add_argument('--add-net',
                    action=ParseIPNets,
                    dest='user_nets',
                    help='Nets subnets for users. Can be used multiple times',
                    default = {})

args = parser.parse_args()
if len(args.user_nets) == 0:
    args.user_nets['user1'] = "198.51.100.0/24"
```

Alternatively, if you want a better user experience, you could make use of the way Python processes mutable default arguments:

```
class ParseIPNets(argparse.Action):
    """docstring for ParseIPNets"""
    def __init__(self, option_strings, dest, nargs=None, **kwargs):
        super(ParseIPNets, self).__init__(option_strings, dest, **kwargs)
    def __call__(self, parser, namespace, values, option_string=None, first=[True]):
        if first[0]:
            namespace.user_nets.clear()
            first[0] = False
        location, subnet = values.split(':')
        namespace.user_nets[location] = subnet

parser.add_argument('--add-net',
                    action=ParseIPNets,
                    dest='user_nets',
                    help='Nets subnets for users. Can be used multiple times',
                    default={"user1": "198.51.100.0/24"})

args = parser.parse_args()
```

That way, the optional default will be cleared if the option is present.

But **BEWARE**: this will work only at first call on the script. It is acceptable here because `parser.parse_args()` should only be called once in a script.

Ancilliary remark: I removed `nargs='*'` because I find it more dangerous than useful here if you call it that way, and also removed the erroneous loop over `values` always using `values`:

```
test.py --add-net=a:10.0.0.0/24 --add-net=b:10.1.0.0/24
```

`nargs='*'` would make sense for following syntax:

```
test.py --add-net a:10.0.0.0/24 b:10.1.0.0/24
```

and the code would be:

```
    def __call__(self, parser, namespace, values, option_string=None, first=[True]):
        if first[0]:
            namespace.user_nets.clear()
            first[0] = False
        for value in values:
            location, subnet = value.split(':')
            namespace.user_nets[location] = subnet
```

Answer (score 1):

It's usually not a good idea to use a mutable default argument (a dict in your case), see [here](http://docs.python-guide.org/en/latest/writing/gotchas/) for an explanation:

> Create a new object each time the function is called, by using a
>   default arg to signal that no argument was provided (None is often a
>   good choice).

Answer (score 0):

My first approach to this problem would be to use `action='append'`, and turn the resulting list into a dictionary after parsing.  The amount of code would be similar.

'append' does have this same issue with defaults.  If `default=['defaultstring']`, then the list will start with that value as well.  I'd get around this by using the default default ([] see below), and add the default in post processing (if the list is still empty or None).

A note on defaults.  At the start of `parse_args`, all action defaults are added to the namespace (unless a namespace was given as a parameter to `parse_args`).  Commandline is then parsed, with each action doing its own thing to the namespace.  At the end, any remaining string defaults are converted with the `type` function.

In your case `namespace.user_nets[location] = subnet` finds the `user_nets` attribute, and adds the new entry.  That attribute was initialized as a dictionary by the default, so the default appears in the final dictionary.  In fact your code would not work if you left the default to be `None` or some string.

The `call` for the `_AppendAction` class may be instructive:

```
def __call__(self, parser, namespace, values, option_string=None):
    items = _copy.copy(_ensure_value(namespace, self.dest, []))
    items.append(values)
    setattr(namespace, self.dest, items)
```

`_ensure_value` is a function defined in `argparse`.  `_copy` is the standard `copy` module that it imported.

`_ensure_value` acts like a dictionary `get(key, value, default)`, except with a `namespace` object.  In this case it returns an empty list if there isn't already a value for `self.dest` (or the value is `None`).  So it ensure that the append starts with a list.

`_copy.copy` ensures that it appends values to a copy.  That way, `parse_args` will not modify the `default`.  It avoids the problem noted by `@miles82`.

So 'append action' defines the initial empty list in the `call` itself.  And uses `copy` to avoid modifying any other default.

Did you want `values` as opposed to `value` in?

```
location, subnet = values.split(':')
```

I'd be inclined to put this conversion in a type function, e.g.

```
def dict_type(astring):
   key, value = astring.split(':')
   return {key:value}
```

This would also be a good place to do error checking.

In the action, or post parsing these could added to the existing dictionay with `update`.