# How to stop processing arguments when using argparse's CustomAction

Tags: python, argparse, pytest

I've implemented a CustomAction in argparse for my python project. The CustomAction is used to be able to specify any number of `name=value` pair style arguments on the command line ie `nargs='*'`.

```
class NameValueAction(argparse.Action):
    """ CustomAction for argparse to be able to process name,value \
       pairs  specified as command line arguments. Specified as

        $ python runner.py --env=target_env --props name1=value1 name2=value2 module/
    """
    def __call__(self, parser, namespace, values, option_string=None):
        for value in values:
            n, v = value.split('=')
            setattr(namespace, n, v)
```

The trouble is that there is no way to stop `__call__` from processing the `module/` argument that is on the command line. How can the `__call__` method be appropriately ended without consuming the `module/` argument and allow for it to be processed by the runner.py?

PS: I've tried exiting on the last argument that is not `name=value` but this does not work, since module has already been consumed and I don't know how to put it back on the stack.

Comment: The parser allocates the `values` list the action gets based on its `nargs`, and the `nargs` of any following actions.  In contrast to `optparse` this action is not peeling values off some master list.  Play around different mixes of positionals, optionals and `nargs` to see how many values each gets.

Comment: Look also at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33301000/custom-parsing-function-for-any-number-of-arguments-in-python-argparse.  It builds a dictionary from multiple `--flag=key:value` strings.

Answer (score 2):

I'll try your latest custom Action:

```
In [34]: parser=argparse.ArgumentParser()

In [35]: parser.add_argument('--env')
In [36]: parser.add_argument('--props',nargs='*',action=NameValueAction)
Out[36]: NameValueAction(option_strings=['--props'], dest='props', nargs='*', const=None, default=None, type=None, choices=None, help=None, metavar=None)
```

I get an `unrecognized arguments` error with `parse_args`.  Your action correctly defined as unknown:

```
In [37]: args=parser.parse_args('--env=target_env --props name1=value1 name2=value2 module/'.split())
usage: ipython2.7 [-h] [--env ENV] [--props [PROPS [PROPS ...]]]
ipython2.7: error: unrecognized arguments: module/
...
```

With parse_known_args I can see the args and extras without the error message:

```
In [38]: parser.parse_known_args('--env=target_env --props name1=value1 name2=value2 module/'.split())
Out[38]: 
(Namespace(env='target_env', name1='value1', name2='value2', props=None),
 ['module/'])
```

So all the strings after `--props` were passed as `values` to that Action.  It assigned the values to the Namespace, and returned.  `parse_known_args` took the `unrecognized` values out of the Namespace and put them in that `extras` list.

---

Now I will add a positional in hopes that it will take the `module/` string:

```
In [39]: parser.add_argument('foo')

In [40]: parser.parse_known_args('--env=target_env --props name1=value1 name2=value2 module/'.split())
usage: ipython2.7 [-h] [--env ENV] [--props [PROPS [PROPS ...]]] foo
ipython2.7: error: too few arguments
...
```

Oops, a different error, even with `parse_known_args`.  The problem is that 'module/' is still being given to `--props`, leaving nothing for `foo`.  `--props` has a `*` nargs, which means it gets everything that qualifies as an argument (no `-`) that follows.  Putting 'module/' in the namespace as `unknown` did not help.  The parser does not reevaluate strings in this list.

I can use '--' to indicate that all strings that follow are positionals.  Now `--props` does not receive or handle 'module\'.  Instead it is consumed by `foo` the next time positionals are handled.

```
In [41]: parser.parse_known_args('--env=target_env --props name1=value1 name2=value2 -- module/'.split())
Out[41]: 
(Namespace(env='target_env', foo='module/', name1='value1', name2='value2', props=None),
 [])
```

Another optional, such as '--env' could be used to mark the end of the '--props' arguments:

```
In [42]: parser.parse_known_args('--props name1=value1 name2=value2 --env=target_env module/'.split())
Out[42]: 
(Namespace(env='target_env', foo='module/', name1='value1', name2='value2', props=None),
 [])
```

Note that `progs=None` appears in the Namespace.  This is because the parser loads all Action defaults into the Namespace at the start of parsing.  You could use `default=argparse.SUPPRESS` to prevent that.

---

See this bugs/issue for explanation on how arguments are allocated to a '*' optional, and what can be done to reserve some for following positionals:

http://bugs.python.org/issue9338
`argparse optionals with nargs='?', '*' or '+' can't be followed by positionals`

https://stackoverflow.com/a/33405960/901925 is another recent SO question that involves a regular positional followed by two '?' positionals.

As I noted in a comment, `argparse` is different from `optparse`.  I believe in `optparse` each Action (or equivalent) consumes as many strings as it wants, and leaves the rest for following Actions.  In `argparse` individual Actions don't have access to the master list (`arg_strings`).  It's the parser that decides how many strings an Action gets.

---

More details from the `argparse.py` file.  It's a summary of the relevant parts of parse_args.

```
 _parse_known_args(self, arg_strings, namespace):
     # arg_strings - master list of strings from sys.argv
     start_index = 0
     while start_index<amax:
         # step through arg_strings processing postionals and optionals
         consume_positionals()
         start_index = next_option_string_index
         start_index = consume_optional(start_index)

consume_optional(start_index): # function local to _parse_known_args
     ...
     start = start_index + 1
     arg_count = <fn of available arguments and nargs>
     stop = start + arg_count
     args = arg_strings[start:stop]
     <action = CustomAction.__call__>
     take_action(action, args, option_string)
     return stop

take_action(action, argument_strings, ...): # another local function
     # argument_strings is a slice of arg_strings
     argument_values = self._get_values(action, argument_strings)
     # _get_values passes strings through the action.type function
     action(self, namespace, argument_values, option_string)
     # no return
```

The net effect is that your `CustomAction.__call__` gets a list of `values` that were derived from a slice of the master `arg_strings` list.  It has no access to `arg_strings`, and no access to the `start` and `stop` of that slice.  So it can't alter the allocation of strings to itself or any subsequent Actions.

---

Another idea is to put the values that you can't parse into `self.dest`.

```
class NameValueAction(argparse.Action):
    def __call__(self, parser, namespace, values,    option_string=None):
        extras = []
        for value in values:
            try:
                n, v = value.split('=')
                setattr(namespace, n, v)
            except ValueError:
                extras.append(value)
        if len(extras):         
            setattr(namespace, self.dest, extras)
```

Then parsing (without the `foo` positional) would produce:

```
In [56]: parser.parse_args('--props name1=value1 p1 name2=value2 module/'.split())
Out[56]: Namespace(env=None, name1='value1', name2='value2', props=['p1', 'module/'])
```

`args.props` now contains `['p1','module/']`, strings that `--props` got, but could not parse as `n=v` pairs.  These can be realocated after parsing as needed.

Comment: "I'll try your latest custom Action" - refers to @tsps or me? [Here's mine on PB](http://pastebin.com/kVfSnjQs).

Comment: I was trying tsps's 2nd try, the one putting the value in the 'unrecognized' attribute.  It doesn't help.

Answer (score 1):

There's no way* to prevent 'module/' from being consumed since it has no `name or flags` associated to indicate that it's a separate argument and not to be consumed by `--props`.

I assume you've setup `--props` as:

```
parser.add_argument('--props', nargs='*', action=NameValueAction)
```

so that will consume as many args as possible. You'd need to give a `-m` or `--module` option to get argparse to store 'module/' separately.

Otherwise, you could put module as a positional arg `parser.add_argument('module')` and specify it before `--props` on the command line:

```
parser.add_argument('--env')
parser.add_argument('--props', nargs='*', action=NameValueAction)
parser.add_argument('module')

""" Usage:
$ python runner.py --env=target_env module/ --props name1=value1 name2=value2
or
$ python runner.py module/ --env=target_env --props name1=value1 name2=value2
"""
```

That processes as:

```
>>> parser.parse_args('--env=target_env module/ --props name1=value1 name2=value2'.split())
Namespace(env='target_env', module='module/', name1='value1', name2='value2', props=None)
```

Btw, using your existing code and without the change suggested above, you could just specify `module=module` at the command line and it will process just like the `name=value` pairs:

```
>>> parser.parse_args('--env=target_env --props name1=value1 name2=value2 module=module/'.split())
Namespace(env='target_env', module='module/', name1='value1', name2='value2', props=None)
```

---

* If you *really* cannot put it as a separate arg, then you'll have to handle it within NameValueAction. I modified the `__call__` in yours as:

```
def __call__(self, parser, namespace, values, option_string=None):
    for value in values:
        try:
            n, v = value.split('=')
            setattr(namespace, n, v)  # better to put this in the else clause actually
        except ValueError:  # "need more than 1 value to unpack"
                            # raised when there's no '=' sign
            setattr(namespace, 'module', value)

>>> parser.parse_args('--env=target_env --props name1=value1 name2=value2 MOARmodules/'.split())
Namespace(env='target_env', module='MOARmodules/', name1='value1', name2='value2', props=None)
```

Of course, the downside of that is how complex the remaining actions are. The one implemented above behaves like `action=store` and will only apply it to `'module'`.

---

You could also try experimenting with appending values to `sys.argv` but considering that's being consumed while you're doing that, may have unexpected side-affects, similar to why you shouldn't insert/delete from a list while iterating over it.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed explanation! The earlier behaviour of this program was without `--props` and module was specified without being an argument. The introduction of `--props` has disturbed the peace a little and changing a whole bunch of dependent scripts would have been needed. To maintain the backwards compatibility I didn't want to use additional flags for parsing the `module` argument. The other trouble is that `module` is an optional argument making it hard to be processed by NameValueAction. After you pointed to handling this in NameValueAction I think I have found a way. See below.

Comment: @tsps Then let module be a positional arg with a default and make `--props` be specified after module. So there's new stuff appended and you can handle module being specified vs missing since that would be the only positional arg.

Comment: Indeed - that's a plausible solution too!

Answer (score 1):

After @aneroid's clue to look into handling within `NameValueAction` I read through the `argparse` module to find a possible way. `Actions` do the command line parsing in `argparse`. An `Action` under `argparse` is triggered on a part of the command line to the program. `argparse` maintains a list of default `Actions` (eg: `store, store_true, const` etc) and `CustomAction` objects that are defined by the user. These are then looped over and processed sequentially against a portion of the command line to find matches and build the `Namespace` corresponding to each `Action`. In each iteration `argparse.Action` may find that part of the command line does not match anything handled by the `Action` and returns them (in the field `_UNRECOGNIZED_ARGS_ATTR` which is identified by the attribute `'_unrecognized_args'` of `Namespace`) back to the caller

From [argparse.py#parse_known_args(..)](https://hg.python.org/cpython/file/2.7/Lib/argparse.py#l1732):

```
try:
    namespace, args = self._parse_known_args(args, namespace)
    if hasattr(namespace, _UNRECOGNIZED_ARGS_ATTR):
        args.extend(getattr(namespace, _UNRECOGNIZED_ARGS_ATTR))
        delattr(namespace, _UNRECOGNIZED_ARGS_ATTR)
    return namespace, args
except ArgumentError:
    err = _sys.exc_info()[1]
    self.error(str(err))
```

As seen above if any unrecognized arguments are found they are returned back to the caller in `args`. The `NameValueAction` class can utilise this to leave them for processing by any other `Actions` that follow or the project's (`runner.py`) module. The class changes thus:

```
class NameValueAction(argparse.Action):
    def __call__(self, parser, namespace, values, option_string=None):
        for value in values:
            try:
                n, v = value.split('=')
                setattr(namespace, n, v)
            except ValueError:
                #  when input has ended without an option, probably at module name
                setattr(namespace, '_unrecognized_args', values[values.index(value):])
```

So the cmd line works as follows:

`$ python runner.py --env=target_env --props name1=value1 name2=value2 module/`

In case additional options are specified after `--props`, `argparse` will stop processing the current `Action` and iterate forward. So the following will also work

`$ python runner.py --env=target_env --props name1=value1 name2=value2 --timeout=300 module/`

Comment: Potentially a nice use of `_UNRECOGNIZED_ARGS_ATTR`.  I'd expect to see 'module/' in the list of `extras` if you use `parse_known_args`.  The only defined Action class that uses this attribute is `subparsers`.

Comment: I think your outline of the parsing method needs some refinement.  I'll try to add something later.

Comment: I was looking for something similar to [`'_unrecognized_args'`](https://hg.python.org/cpython/file/2.7/Lib/argparse.py#l1732), or basically a mechanism to add something to the 'to-parse' queue/list. Too bad that it's not _documented_ or has an exposed method to access and modify it.

Comment: `_unrecognized_args` is just a way for subparsers to pass `extras` back to the main parser.  It doesn't go back on a queue.

Answer (score 1):

(Answering only because I also needed to "eat" a number of arguments unknown beforehand from the list and the solution below is reasonably generic.)

As @hpaulj mentioned above, using positional arguments won't work without subclassing `ArgumentParser` as the parser simply passes everything to the `Action`, however if you just want options parsed and get non-option arguments back as a list (ie. passing them to a different parser), the following works (on Python 3.4 at least):

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import argparse
import itertools

class EatUnknown(argparse.Action):
    def __init__(self, option_strings, dest, nargs=None, *args, **kwargs):
        nargs = argparse.REMAINDER
        super().__init__(option_strings, dest, nargs, *args, **kwargs)

    def __call__(self, parser, namespace, values, option_string=None):
        def all_opt_strings(parser):
            nested = (x.option_strings for x in parser._actions
                      if x.option_strings)
            return itertools.chain.from_iterable(nested)

        all_opts = list(all_opt_strings(parser))

        eaten = []
        while len(values) > 0:
            if values[0] in all_opts:
                break
            eaten.append(values.pop(0))
        setattr(namespace, self.dest, eaten)

        _, extras = parser._parse_known_args(values, namespace)
        try:
            getattr(namespace, argparse._UNRECOGNIZED_ARGS_ATTR).extend(extras)
        except AttributeError:
            setattr(namespace, argparse._UNRECOGNIZED_ARGS_ATTR, extras)

parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
parser.add_argument("--foo", action="append")
parser.add_argument('--eatme', action=EatUnknown)
parser.add_argument('--eater', action=EatUnknown)

print(parser.parse_known_args())
```

Produces

```
$ ./argparse_eater.py --foo 1 AAA --eater 2 --unk-opt 3 --foo 4 BBB --eatme 5 --another-unk --foo 6 CCC
(Namespace(eater=['2', '--unk-opt', '3'], eatme=['5', '--another-unk'], foo=['1', '4', '6']), ['AAA', 'CCC', 'BBB'])
```

This example "eats up" any non-options as well as unknown option arguments (where `nargs='*'` cannot be used, justifying the example), though is not `allow_abbrev` compatible.

The idea is to use a simple recursion, which apparently works as the code is reentrant. Probably not the best idea to rely upon, but using `_unrecognized_args` is not much better.

Given the OP, this would work for multiple occurences of `--props`.